# zsh keeps sharing history even when shared history is disabled

Tags: zsh, prezto

I'm using zsh with prezto (on OSX and inside tmux, not sure if it matters), and from time to time history gets shared between multiple terminals.

I already added unsetopt share_history and also unsetopt SHARE_HISTORY to the end of my .zpreztorc, but it keeps mixing up history.

The output of setopt shows that "sharehistory" is still there! Even after adding unsetopt sharehistory.

Comment: The output of `setopt` might help show what options are set, if you don't know how your shell is configured.

Comment: @thrig updated my answer with the output of setopt. "sharehistory" is there o.O

Comment: Okay, what does something like `zsh -xic exit 2>&1 | fgrep '> setopt '` show happening (or make your changes *after* prezto does whatever it does).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try adding:

```
setopt no_share_history
unsetopt share_history
```

to ~/.zshrc ... this should work